# I'm using windows7 and Pycharm 2019.3 with Python 3, Can't find the solution to cvtColor command in the code below:

Tags: python, opencv

The error that arises is:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:259: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
```

Where `scn` is 1.

Please help me:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = r'C:\Users\Vinay\Desktop\picture.jpg'

eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Python/tutorial/Classifiers/haarscascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread(img,0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(500)

img2=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Python/tutorial/Classifiers/haarscascade_eye.xml'), img, 1.3, 5)
eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 5)
for (x, y, w, h) in eyes:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(img.shape)`?

Answer (score 0):

While reading the image you have specified `imread(img, 0)` which means the image will be automatically be read in Grayscale so there is no need to convert it to gray using `cvtColor`.

However if you want to access it as a colored image somewhere make the imread line as `imread(img)` and convert it to grayscale using `cvtColor`.

Comment: Yeah! Corrected.